# Remove jQuery plugin without reloading content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Say I have two different functionalities/filters (e.g. calculation and sorting) in form of plugins for a table. The user can choose which one he wants to use right now. But both together have conflicts and therefore when one is chosen, the other should be stopped/removed (without reloading the table itself). How can I achieve that?

For example I use the `dataTable` jQuery plugin which is initialized by

`$('#myTable').dataTable();`

But when the user chooses a different filter, I somehow need to 'deactivate' this plugin for the other filter to work without conflict. I tried the `unbind` event handler, but without success.

In general the logic would look like this:

```
$('.js_trigger').on('click', '.calculation' function() {
    //Deactivate
    $('#myTable').dataTable();
    //Activate
    $('#myTable').dataCalculation();
}

$('.js_trigger').on('click', '.sorting' function() {
    //Deactivate
    $('#myTable').dataCalculation();
    //Activate
    $('#myTable').dataTable();
}
```

I hope you get what I mean and that this question is not to broad.

**Solution:**

With the hint of @V31, I made use of the `empty()` function.

1.) On page load I put all the content from the table in a variable before any additional scripts change the table.

```
tableContent = $('#myTableContainer').html();
```

2.) When a different plugin needs to be loaded I empty the container and add the content of the variable before I execute the plugin.

```
$('#myTableContainer').empty();
$('#myTableContainer').html(tableContent);
$('#myTable').dataTable();
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are looking for/expecting, but dataTable plugin accepts a destroy method, maybe fitting your needs: http://datatables.net/reference/option/destroy

Comment: *"without reloading the table itself"* but... that's exactly what emptying the table does.

Comment: @KevinB Yes you are correct. I meant reloading more in the sense of `ajax` or a complete page refresh. Sorry if my description was confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can empty the parent div (of that element) so that the binding is removed. Something like this:

```
$('#myTable').empty();
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer pointed me in the right direction. If you are interested, I updated my question accordingly.